# VisualWorks Cincom Smalltalk Array Initialization Differences

Tags: smalltalk

```
|temp|
temp := Array new: 5.
temp at: 1 put: 10.
```

Gives no error.

```
|temp|
temp := #(1 2 3 4 5).
temp at: 1 put: 10.
```

Gives error

What is the difference b/w the two ways of initializing arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## (1 2 3 4 5) is an immutable array.

It cannot be modified.

Array new: 10 is a non immutable array. It can be modified.

Comment: Yup... and a copy of an immutable array is non immutable, so you could use: #(1 2 3 4 5) copy.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, #(1 2 3 4 5) results in an immutable array and raises an exception when you try to write to it.  I thought I'd explain the rationale for introducing the concept of immutable collections.

Smalltalk compiles source code into instances of the class CompiledMethod.  A CompiledMethod contains bytecodes (bytes representing the instructions to execute by a virtual machine) and literals.  Literals are objects that are created by the compiler that are referenced by the method.

Consider the following code:

```
isSmallPrime: aNumber
    ^#(2 3 5 7 11) includes: aNumber
```

The object #(2 3 5 7 11) is an Array that's stored as a literal in the CompiledMethod.  The problem, then, is that if you can change values in the literal you effectively change what the code does without having a change to the source code.  Looking at the code it appears to do one thing but in reality it does something else.

Consider the following example:

```
isSmallPrime: aNumber
    ^self smallPrimes includes: aNumber

smallPrimes
    ^#(2 3 5 7 11)

corrupt
  self smallPrimes at: 1 put: 4
```

If you call corrupt, you'll change the literal array of the smallPrimes method to #(4 3 5 7 11). Even though the source code says that smallPrimes returns #(2 3 5 7 11) it really returns #(4 3 5 7 11) because it was clobbered by the corrupt method.  Subsequently, calling isSmallPrime: 2 will return false and isSmallPrime: 4 returns true.  This becomes very confusing because we normally assume that the method always behaves the way the source code says it does.  Here we have a case where the source code says one thing and the method does a different thing.

To guard against this problem, VisualWorks introduced the concept of immutable literals. Any attempt to write to a literal object (such as in the corrupt method) would raise an exception to ensure that the operation of the code matches what the source code says the code does.